# Error Uncaught ReferenceError, Quantity is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I believe the problem is in the function createpo, but I am unsure. The function is meant to take information from different Google Sheets and create a new Google Sheet by clicking a button, and this code is modeled after a Purchase Order creator. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function AddItem()
{
  
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MENU SHEET          
  var poSheet = ss.getSheetByName("QAR");
  var itemSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ITEMS");
  
  //GET NEXT ROW OF PO SHEET
  var lastrowPO = poSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  //GET LAST ROW OF ITEM SHEET
  var lastrowItem = itemSheet.getLastRow();
  
   //GET VALUE OF PART AND QUANTITY
  var part = poSheet.getRange('B13').getValue();
  var quantity = poSheet.getRange('B14').getValue();  
  
  // GET UNIT PRICE FROM ITEM SHEET
  for(var i = 2; i <= lastrowItem; i++)
  {
    if (part == itemSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue())
    {
      var description = itemSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var unitCost = itemSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    }
  }
  
  // POPULATE PO SHEET
  poSheet.getRange(lastrowPO, 1).setValue(part);
  poSheet.getRange(lastrowPO, 2).setValue(description);
  poSheet.getRange(lastrowPO, 3).setValue(quantity);
  poSheet.getRange(lastrowPO, 4).setValue(unitCost).setNumberFormat("$#,###.00");
  
}


function createPO()
{
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MENU SHEET          
  var poSheet = ss.getSheetByName("QAR");
  var vendorSheet = ss.getSheetByName("VENDORS");
  var settingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SETTINGS");
  var printSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PRINT QAR");
  
  //GET VALUES
  var name = poSheet.getRange(6,2).getValue();
  var invoice_number = poSheet.getRange(7,2).getValue();
  var ship_date = poSheet.getRange(8,2).getValue();
  var ship_via = poSheet.getRange(9,2).getValue();
  var terms = poSheet.getRange(10,2).getValue();
  var ship_and_handle = poSheet.getRange(11,2).getValue();
  var po_number = settingSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  var next_po_number = po_number + 1;
  settingSheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(next_po_number);
  
  // GET VENDOR LAST ROW
  var lastrowVendor = vendorSheet.getLastRow();
  
  // GET CUSTOMER FIELDS
  for(var i = 2; i <= lastrowVendor; i++)
  {
    if(name == vendorSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue())
    {
      var companyName = vendorSheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      var streetAddress = vendorSheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      var city = vendorSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
      var state = vendorSheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
      var zip = vendorSheet.getRange(i,6).getValue();
      var phone_number = vendorSheet.getRange(i,7).getValue();
      var email = vendorSheet.getRange(i,8).getValue();
      var tax_rate = vendorSheet.getRange(i,9).getValue();
    }
  }
  
  // SET PO DATE
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  var date = currentMonth.toString() + '/' + currentDate.getDate().toString() + '/' + currentYear.toString();


  
  // SET VALUES ON PO  
  printSheet.getRange('B19').setValue(name).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B20').setValue(companyName).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B21').setValue(streetAddress).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B22').setValue(city +', ' + state + ' ' + zip).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B23').setValue(phone_number).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B24').setValue(email).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  
  printSheet.getRange('B12').setValue(date).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('D12').setValue(invoice_number).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('F12').setValue(po_number).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B15').setValue(ship_date).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('D15').setValue(ship_via).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("3e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('F15').setValue(terms).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("3e01b84");
  
  printSheet.getRange('H28').setValue(ship_and_handle).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('H29').setValue(tax_rate).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  
  
  var totalPO = subTotal;
  var subTotal = 0;
  // PRICE TOTALS
    var totalPrice = quantity * unitPrice;
    subTotal = subTotal + totalPrice;
    
  
 // CALL PO LOG
  POLog(po_number, name, date, ship_date, totalPO)

}

function POLog(po_number, name, date, ship_date, totalPO)
{
  
   //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE PO LOG SHEET          
  var POLogSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PO LOG"); 
  
  //GET LAST ROW OF PO LOG SHEET
  var nextRowPO = POLogSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  //POPULATE INVOICE LOG
  POLogSheet.getRange(nextRowPO, 1).setValue(po_number);
  POLogSheet.getRange(nextRowPO, 2).setValue(name);
  POLogSheet.getRange(nextRowPO, 3).setValue(date);
  POLogSheet.getRange(nextRowPO, 4).setValue(ship_date);
  POLogSheet.getRange(nextRowPO, 5).setValue(totalPO);

}

function ClearInvoice()
{
    //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE PO SHEET          
  var poSheet = ss.getSheetByName("QAR");
  
  
  //SET VALUES TO NOTHING
  poSheet.getRange(6,2).setValue("");
  poSheet.getRange(7,2).setValue("");  
  poSheet.getRange(9,2).setValue("");  
  poSheet.getRange(10,2).setValue(""); 
  poSheet.getRange(11,2).setValue(""); 
  poSheet.getRange(13,2).setValue("");  
  

}
```

Comment: `Quantity` is not defined indeed. `quantity` is, on the other hand. Are you sure that is the error you are getting? Where did you write `Quantity` ? It doesn't appear anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message with the specific line number. I believe there is a problem in your implementation in `createPO()` particularly this lines of code `var totalPO = subTotal;
  var subTotal = 0;
  // PRICE TOTALS
    var totalPrice = quantity * unitPrice;
    subTotal = subTotal + totalPrice;`. Where `subTotal` is not defined yet when you assign to `totalPO`, `quantity` undefined and `unitPrice` as well.

Comment: Looks like unitPrice is undefined as well

Comment: I figured it out! Looks like I had to just define all of the variables again, which I do not understand because I already had defined them all early. Why is that? Otherwise, thanks for the help!

Comment: now I am not receiving an error message, but am running into a problem where not all of the totals are showing up. I am unsure of where in the code the functions are being found, any help would be great.

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet with your expected output. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: Here is the sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a5QHoledlXyB-P_mHfcX18x4akSd22HYujlaobGRIjU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you describe which specific functionality is not working? is it `createPO()` ?? and can you explain your expected output? Please explain what are you trying to accomplish

Comment: I am unsure which functionality is not working, I am fairly certain it is createPO() however. I am attempting to fix the calculations and formulas in the "PRINT QAR" sheet, because if you look the total price per SKU (or different flavor of sauce) is not being calculated. I have a hunch it has something to do with one of the lastrow functions, but can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

### Pre-requisite:

- Update the formula in `QAR` Sheet and use ARRAYFORMULA() to get the item details just by using 1 formula.

---

```
**QAR!B17:** =arrayformula(if(A17:A<>"",Iferror(VLOOKUP(A17:A,ITEMS!A2:E30,2,false),""),""))

**QAR!C17:** =arrayformula(if(A17:A<>"",iferror(VLOOKUP(A17:A,F4:I17,2,False),""),""))

**QAR!D17:** =arrayformula(if(A17:A<>"",iferror(VLOOKUP(A17:A,ITEMS!A2:C33,3,false),""),""))
```

- Create a `PRINT QAR` Template sheet.

### You can refer to this sample code:

```
function createPO()
{
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MENU SHEET          
  var poSheet = ss.getSheetByName("QAR");
  var vendorSheet = ss.getSheetByName("VENDORS");
  var settingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SETTINGS");
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PRINT QAR_Template");
  var printSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PRINT QAR");

  //Delete Existing "PRINR QAR" Sheet
  ss.deleteSheet(printSheet);

  //Create a new "PRINR QAR" Sheet from the "PRINT QAR_Template" Sheet
  printSheet = templateSheet.copyTo(ss);
  printSheet.setName("PRINT QAR")
  
  //GET VALUES
  var name = poSheet.getRange(6,2).getValue();
  var invoice_number = poSheet.getRange(7,2).getValue();
  var ship_date = poSheet.getRange(8,2).getValue();
  var ship_via = poSheet.getRange(9,2).getValue();
  var terms = poSheet.getRange(10,2).getValue();
  var ship_and_handle = poSheet.getRange(11,2).getValue();
  var po_number = settingSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  var next_po_number = po_number + 1;
  
  
  // GET VENDOR LAST ROW
  var lastrowVendor = vendorSheet.getLastRow();
  
  // GET CUSTOMER FIELDS
  for(var i = 2; i <= lastrowVendor; i++)
  {
    if(name == vendorSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue())
    {
      var companyName = vendorSheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      var streetAddress = vendorSheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      var city = vendorSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
      var state = vendorSheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
      var zip = vendorSheet.getRange(i,6).getValue();
      var phone_number = vendorSheet.getRange(i,7).getValue();
      var email = vendorSheet.getRange(i,8).getValue();
      var tax_rate = vendorSheet.getRange(i,9).getValue();
    }
  }

  // SET PO DATE
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  var date = currentMonth.toString() + '/' + currentDate.getDate().toString() + '/' + currentYear.toString();


  // SET VALUES ON PO  
  printSheet.getRange('B19').setValue(name).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B20').setValue(companyName).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B21').setValue(streetAddress).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B22').setValue(city +', ' + state + ' ' + zip).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B23').setValue(phone_number).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B24').setValue(email).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  
  printSheet.getRange('B12').setValue(date).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('D12').setValue(invoice_number).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('F12').setValue(po_number).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('B15').setValue(ship_date).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('D15').setValue(ship_via).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("3e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('F15').setValue(terms).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("3e01b84");
  
  printSheet.getRange('H28').setValue(ship_and_handle).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  printSheet.getRange('H29').setValue(tax_rate).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#ce1212");
  
  //Read Item details in "QAR" Sheet starting from row 17 (Column A to Column D)
  var itemCount = poSheet.getRange('A17:A').getValues().flat().filter(String).length;
  var itemValues = poSheet.getRange(17,1,itemCount,4).getValues();
  var startRow = 26;
  printSheet.insertRowsAfter(startRow, itemCount);
  var totalPO = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<itemCount; i++){
    var row = itemValues[i];
    var total = row[2] * row[3];
    startRow++;
    printSheet.getRange(startRow,2).setValue(row[0]).setFontFamily('Arial').setFontSize(12).setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor('black');
    printSheet.getRange(startRow,3).setValue(row[1]).setFontFamily('Arial').setFontSize(12).setFontWeight("normal").setFontColor('black');
    printSheet.getRange(startRow,6).setValue(row[2]).setFontFamily('Arial').setFontSize(12).setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor("#ce1212");
    printSheet.getRange(startRow,7).setValue("$"+row[3]).setFontFamily('Arial').setFontSize(12).setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor("#ce1212");
    printSheet.getRange(startRow,8).setValue("$"+total).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(12).setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor("#ce1212");
    totalPO+=total;
  }

  //Set subtotal and shipping handling cell
  Logger.log(totalPO);
  printSheet.getRange(startRow+1,8).setValue("$"+totalPO).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(12).setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor('black');
  printSheet.getRange(startRow+3,7).setValue("$"+totalPO).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(20).setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor("#ce1212");


 // CALL PO LOG
  POLog(po_number, name, date, ship_date, totalPO)

}
```

### Modifications done:

1. Delete existing `PRINT QAR` Sheet
2. Create a new `PRINT QAR` Sheet from the template sheet `PRINT QAR_Template`
3. Get the Item details in `QAR` Sheet starting from row 17 (for Column A to D)
4. Insert a new row based on the item count in `PRINT QAR` Sheet after row 26
5. Update the newly added row based on the item details. Compute for the total price while looping each items

### Output:

[image]

Refer to this [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ikuhVRZ6XrcKQzixf2Kwgyn9g54dB91i92MK8OMFctc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please let me know if this is the issue you are referring to and if you have some issues with the solution so I could update it accordingly

Comment: Ron, I understand that much however when you create another QAR, those formulas get wiped away again. Unless the only solution is dragging the formula every time, I was looking for a way to work that into the code.

Comment: I updated the answer, please let me know if this resolves your concern